# For Next Loop Freezing

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code to search a list of dates and delete any rows associated with a date prior to two years ago.  When I run, excel freezes.  I'm new to VBA, and think I'm probably having a conceptual misunderstanding regarding using this particular loop:

```
Sub DeletePriorDates()
'Delete any dates before two years past
    Dim twoyrpast As Date
    Dim c As Range
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = Sheet6.Range("A:A")
    twoyrpast = DateAdd("yyyy", -2, Sheet1.[B].Value)

    For Each c In DataRange
        If c < twoyrpast Then c.EntireRow.Delete
    Next

End Sub
```

When I stop running the macro, the debugger highlights the "Next".  I've tried different iterations of Next, and code online seems almost identical.  I can't find what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: When deleting rows it is recommended to run the loop backwards i.e. `For i = 100 to 1 Step -1` Your issue is caused as you're putting it into an infinite loop by setting your DataRange to the entire Column

Comment: Ok, that's good to know.  I'm not familiar, but I'll look it up now.  Thanks for your response! @Tom

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Further to my comment above give this a go

```
Public Sub DeletePriorDates()
'Delete any dates before two years past
    Dim twoyrpast As Date
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheet6
        twoyrpast = DateAdd("yyyy", -2, Sheet1.[B].Value)

        For i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(i, 1) < twoyrpast Then .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```